# prism navigation: I can requestnavigate to only one particular view

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

Im using prism 4.0, wpf,

I create RegionAdapter for devx DocumentGroup.

I have a view which is shown as content of DocumentPanel(child of DocumentGroup).
I register view in container. everything fine. I can request view into the region of DocumentGroup.

```
container.RegisterType<Object, NatLossesView>("NatLossesView",new TransientLifetimeManager());
```

The problem:
I can create only one view in DocumentGroup items.
For example, my program is loaded, no document on the panel.
I do

`var NatLossesViewU = new Uri("NatLossesView", UriKind.Relative);
regionManager.RequestNavigate("DocumentGroupRegion", NatLossesViewU);`

The view is shown. I'd like to create one more instance of view, but calling previous code does nothing. After I close the view, I can call my code and the view is shown again

**SOLVED**

I've solved my issue myself. ViewModel has to implement [INavigationAware](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.regions.inavigationaware.isnavigationtarget%28v=pandp.38%29.aspx) interface.
method [IsNavigationTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.regions.inavigationaware.isnavigationtarget%28v=pandp.38%29.aspx) should be like this:

```
public bool IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext)
{
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming in your region adpater you are making sure the added view is properly added to your docnwindowgroup items list - try following code,

```
var NatLossesViewobj = _container.Resolve<NatLossesView>() 
regionManager.AddToRegion("DocumentGroupRegion", NatLossesViewobj);
```

Comment: Yes you are right. thats how I add views now, it works indeed, thanks. But there is a problem. In this way I need a direct reference to the module which has this view. I do not want to have references between the modules :-(

Comment: @Yuriy, could you not just move the view into a control library?

Comment: @Bot, I'd like to divide the app by logical modules. I'd like not to load a module if it is not required (not to load view, viewmodels, resources)